# How to bind bool values to checkbox in repeater?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I want to bind bool value to repeater .

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
<br />
<img ID="ImageZoom" runat="server" src='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ImageUrl") %> '  style="display: inline; height:auto; left: 0pt; top: 0pt; width:auto;" />
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ImageId") %> ' Checked='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Boolv") %>' /> 

</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Here on page load checked should have only true or false but its returning checked . How can i get true or false ?

Answer (score 2):

Instead to fiddling around on the aspx markup, i would do that in `ItemDataBound`:

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    RepeaterItem ri = e.Item;
    DataRowView dr = (DataRowView)ri.DataItem;
    CheckBox CheckBox1 = (CheckBox)ri.FindControl("CheckBox1");
    CheckBox1.Checked = (bool)dr["Boolv"];
}
```

Comment: @user1619151: Is `Boolv` a boolean at all? You say that _"its returning checked"_ instead of `true/false`. Maybe you've stored a string _"checked"_. Then try this: `CheckBox1.Checked = dr["Boolv"].Equals("checked");`.

Comment: ya . i did , its correctly coming there when i debug , but in ascx page I am getting like above . I saw this by using inspect element

Answer (score 0):

several days ago, I also had a problem with repeater and a checkbox in it. I wanted to bind the value of the checkbox to bool variable.

Here is my post. I've solved my problem using the accepted answer in the post.
[answer link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12073670/set-checkbox-checked-propery-in-asp-repeater)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I you want to dot this in clientSide use `eval if statement`

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ImageId") %> ' Checked='<%# ((int)Eval("Boolv")) == 1 ? Checked : false %>' />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `OnItemDataBound` `event` on `Repeater` `Control`

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792658/asp-net-visual-studio-repeater-with-linkbuttons/11792746#11792746) my answer to similar question

hope it's help:)

Answer (score 0):

In one of my implementations, I was getting 1 and 0 from database for the boolean value so my implementation for it was as:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkAssign" runat="server" Checked=<%# TranslateAction(((System.Data.DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["ISACTIVE"].ToString())%> />
```

and in the code behind I had a method named TranslateAction as:

```
protected Boolean TranslateAction(String status)
{
    if (status == "1")
        return true;
     else
        return false;
}
```

I hope it will help you in it.